# Read image from resources folder

Tags: java

I want to read image from resources folder and send it as a response body. I tried this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{imageid}",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable int imageid) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("/resources/color.jpg")));
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

But I get: `threw exception
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: null
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)`

The file `color.jpg` is located there but for some reason is not found. Do you know how I can solve this issue?

```
Directory of C:\Users\........war_file\src\main\resources

10/04/2020  20:58    <DIR>          .
10/04/2020  20:58    <DIR>          ..
10/04/2020  20:05               816 application-dev.yml
10/04/2020  19:26               816 application-local.yml
10/04/2020  20:05               813 application.yml
10/04/2020  20:58           187,405 color.jpg
11/03/2020  01:43               795 logback-spring.xml
               5 File(s)        190,645 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  48,421,285,888 bytes free
```

EDIT: The solution:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/{imageid}",method= RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable int imageid) throws IOException {

        ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("color.jpg");
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on Spring Boot 2.2.6.RELEASE.

```
@Controller
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/image/{imageid}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody
    byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable int imageid) throws IOException {

        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:color.jpg");
        File file = resource.getFile();
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [color.jpg] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/C:/Users/......jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/color.jpg`

Comment: Do you have a file on your resources directory named "color.jpg"? Can you show your resource folder content list?

Comment: @PeterPenzov better share the whole package structure of the project.

Comment: How I can do this in Intelij?

Comment: I tried this: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/C:/color.jpg] cannot be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?`

Comment: It would not work, better share the whole project directory structure so it's much easier to understand what you have.

Comment: see the post. I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/color.jpg"))
```

Try only "color.jpg" without "/resources" (`getClass().getResource("color.jpg"))`). Because you already get resource. Also be sure you setted your resources folder.

Comment: Now I get NULL here: `byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Try `getClass().getResource("/resources/color.jpg").getFile()` instead `String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("/resources/color.jpg"))`.

Comment: I get NPE here `File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/resources/color.jpg").getFile());`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Oh sorry, I wrote wrong. You must use `getClass().getResource("color.jpg").getFile()`

Comment: @PeterPenzov Are you sure you setted resources folder.

Comment: hm.. .what do you mean by setted?

Comment: For example, you must set folder as resource folder in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: I compile the Spring project, then I run it using `java -jar target\hr-site-1.0.jar` and using Postaman I make request to this endpoint.

Comment: What is your project tree like that?

Comment: yes, but it's too huge to display it into one picture.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is a Spring boot project, you can access any files from resources as below

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("color.jpg").getFile()); //Remove "resources"
```

Comment: I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: null`